# Função Random Python Monte Carlo

Tags: python, random

Preciso gerar números aleatórios.Uma quantidade de números na casa de 10^5 e 10^6 numeros aleatorios.

A função randint da biblioteca random me parece que não possue um grau de  aleatoriedade bom quando gera tantos numeros repetidos assim.Alguem sabe uma biblioteca com uma função random melhor para ser utilizada em simulação monte carlo?

É possivel renovar a semente da função randint?De forma a ter um grau de aleatoriedade boa nessa escala?

Comment: Por que a função randint não parece possuir grau de aleatoriedade bom? Se quiser números aleatórios mais seguros, pode usar uma biblioteca de criptografia como a `pycryptodome`.

Comment: Porque apos gerar muitos números a função começa a gerar números em sequencia, e ou ,o mesmo numero com um grau de frequência muito alto

Comment: Por curiosidade, como determinou que a função gera números em sequencia? Fazendo um [teste rápido](https://gist.github.com/pedrovhb/a35e6740db43891e249901f45d05060f), a distribuição me parece bem razoável.

Comment: Talvez isto ajude, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22639587/3162303

Comment: Coloque o código que está a utilizar que fica mais facil de ajudar. Não estará a usar o mesmo `seed` para gerar vários dos números ?

Comment: Pedro von , não foi isso que eu fiz ,mas por esse caminho você chegará a mesma conclusão : crie um vetor de tamanho x com valores 0  . Vetor [x]  . Mande a função Random selecionar valores entre 0 e X . Vá na posição do vetor igual ao valor selecionado pela função random e mande somar uma unidade .Repita esseprocedimento numa ordem de 10 ^6 . E verá que algumas posições do vetor possuem valores muito maiores aos outros . Ou seja, esse valor foi selecionado muito mais que os outros .não sendo assim de fato aleatório ,para ser os valores tinha que ser + ou - iguais .

Comment: @VitorBento [também dá um valor bem razoável](https://gist.github.com/pedrovhb/17cee5dab90693a7c8772a946106a15a). Se você postar o código que está o levando a tirar essas conclusões, talvez consigamos descobrir o problema.